# Why is there a $2\pi$ in $\int dk ~ e^{ik(x-x')} =2\pi~\delta(x-x')$?

Tags: fourier-transform, mathematics, dirac-delta-distributions

This comes up in Physics from Symmetry by Jakob Schwichtenberg.

> That's where the factors of $2\pi$ come from. Another way of seeing this is demanding the solutions to form an orthonormal set:
> $$\int dk ~ e^{ikx} e^{ikx'} = \int dk ~ e^{ik(x-x')} = 2\pi ~ \delta(x-x').$$
> Therefore, the factors of $2\pi$ are normalization constants.

I see that the integral will be zero when $x \not= x'$ because the function will oscillate equally above and below. But I don't see how the integral $\frac{\int dk}{2\pi}$ is normalized to equal $1$.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I usually understand physicists better. But, probably.

Comment: Related: [On Dirac delta definition](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/729603)

Comment: “I don't see how the integral $\frac{\int dk}{2\pi}$ is normalized to equal 1.” You seem to be thinking that $\delta(0)$ is $1$; it’s $\infty$ (loosely speaking).

Comment: @Ghoster thanks. that's right. i was confused.

Comment: I've found another answer on mathematics.stackexchange.https://math.stackexchange.com/q/301860/

Comment: maybe this question should be closed considering someone asked basically the same question earlier today.

Comment: @Qmechanic not that I necessarily disagree with closing this one, but does it make sense to close it as duplicate of a post that was also closed as off-topic? Shouldn't they both be just flagged as off-topic (they'll be linked anyway via the comments)?

Comment: @glS: Comments could be deleted. Sometimes we close off-topic not-exact-duplicates as duplicates to serve as a pointer for the reader. If we migrate to [math.se] it will likely also be closed.